# Can't get specific image to load and stay there untill change to another by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having a problem with a site menu, it's a hotsite and I can only have two pages. So First is a regular index.html, that leads to the second, and there I call many other pages by php. However, the menu on top that are the circles and the side menu, stay the same. I just chnge the sub menu and the content inside each link.

All working, but my menu, needs to stay kind of active, so I tried to change the images just like the hover. But it didn't work. The image needs to stay on if I click on 2009, or 2010, or 2011

Any thoughts on that?

you canfind it at www.neevasoft.com/inofar

The circles menus

Here is the code and the CSS.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>INCT INOFAR</title>

  <?
  $tipo = $_GET['tipo'];
  $pagina = $_GET['pagina'];
  $paginatit = $_GET['paginatit'];
  $submenu = $_GET['submenu'];
  ?>

  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,700'   rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/padrao-interno.css"/>

 <script type="text/javascript"  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#divmenuano a").click(function( e ){
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = $( this ).attr('href');
        $("#divmiolo").load( href +" #divmiolo");
    });
   });
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#Mostradiv2015').click(function () {
    this.attr('src', '/imagens/2015-on.png');
    $('#Mostradiv2015').attr('src','/imagens/2015-on.png');
});
});
   </script>

  </head> 

  <body>
<table class="base" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr class="cabecalho">
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td  class="lados">&nbsp;</td>


<td class="conteudo"><!-- INICIO DO LAYOUT -->


<div id="divtopo">

<div id="divlogo"><a href="index.html" target="_top"  class="titulotop"   >INCT INOFAR</a></div>
  <div  id="divsublogo">ANNUAL ACTVITIES REPORT <b>2015</b></div>

 </div>

 <div id="divmenuano">

<ul class="menuanual">
<li class="menuanual">

            <a class="a2015" href="inct-inofar2.php?tipo=top&submenu=highlight&pagina=2015&paginatit=2013tit.html"> 
            <div id="a2015_efeito">
                <img src="imagens/2015-off.png" onmouseover="this.src='imagens/2015-on.png'" onmouseout="this.src='imagens/2015-off.png'" title="2015" id="Mostradiv2015" >
            </div>  
            </a>

    </li>
    <li class="menuanual1">
        <div id="a2014_efeito">
            <a class="a2014" href="inct-inofar2.php?tipo=top&submenu=highlights&pagina=2014&paginatit=2013tit.html"> 
                <img src="imagens/2014-off.png" onmouseover="this.src='imagens/2014-on.png'" onmouseout="this.src='imagens/2014-off.png'" title="2014" onclick="marcar('2014')" id="Mostradiv2014" >
            </a>
        </div>
     </li>
     <li class="menuanual2">
        <div id="a2013_efeito">
            <a class="a2013" href="inct-inofar2.php?tipo=top&submenu=events&pagina=2013&paginatit=2013tit.html"> 
                <img src="imagens/2013-off.png" onmouseover="this.src='imagens/2013-on.png'" onmouseout="this.src='imagens/2013-off.png'"title="2013" onclick="marcar('2013')" id="Mostradiv2013" >
            </a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="menuanual3">
    <div id="a2012_efeito">
        <a class="a2012" href="inct-inofar2.php?tipo=top&submenu=highlight&pagina=2012&paginatit=2013tit.html"> 
            <img src="imagens/2012-off.png" onmouseover="this.src='imagens/2012-on.png'" onmouseout="this.src='imagens/2012-off.png'"title="2012" onclick="marcar('2012')" id="Mostradiv2012" >
        </a>
    </div>
    </li>
    <li class="menuanual4">
    <div id="a2011_efeito">
        <a class="a2011" href="inct-inofar2.php?tipo=top&submenu=highlight&pagina=2011&paginatit=2013tit.html"> 
            <img src="imagens/2011-off.png" onmouseover="this.src='imagens/2011-on.png'" onmouseout="this.src='imagens/2011-off.png'" title="2011" onclick="marcar('2011')" id="Mostradiv2011" >
        </a>
    </div>
    </li>
    <li class="menuanual5">
    <div id="a2010_efeito">
        <a class="a2010" href="inct-inofar2.php?tipo=top&submenu=highlights&pagina=2010&paginatit=2013tit.html"> 
            <img src="imagens/2010-off.png" onmouseover="this.src='imagens/2010-on.png'" onmouseout="this.src='imagens/2010-off.png'"title="2010" onclick="marcar('2010')" id="Mostradiv2010" >
    </a>
    </div>
    </li>
    <li class="menuanual6">
    <div id="a2009_efeito">
        <a class="a2009" href="inct-inofar2.php?tipo=top&submenu=highlights&pagina=2009&paginatit=2013tit.html"> 
            <img src="imagens/2009-off.png" onmouseover="this.src='imagens/2009-on.png'" onmouseout="this.src='imagens/2009-off.png'"title="2009" onclick="marcar('2009')" id="Mostradiv2009" >
        </a>
        </div>  
        </li>
       </ul>
       </div>
```

CSS

```
  ul.menuanual{list-style-type:none; padding-left:530px; width:725px; height:77px;}

        li.menuanual, a.a2015, a.a2014, a.a2013, a.a2012, a.a2011, a.a2010, a.a2009{float:left; margin-left: -9px; margin-right:31px;}
        li.menuanual1, a.a2015, a.a2014, a.a2013, a.a2012, a.a2011, a.a2010, a.a2009{float:left; margin-right:31px;}
        li.menuanual2, a.a2015, a.a2014, a.a2013, a.a2012, a.a2011, a.a2010, a.a2009{float:left; margin-right:32px;}
        li.menuanual3, a.a2015, a.a2014, a.a2013, a.a2012, a.a2011, a.a2010, a.a2009{float:left; margin-right:31px;}
        li.menuanual4, a.a2015, a.a2014, a.a2013, a.a2012, a.a2011, a.a2010, a.a2009{float:left; margin-right:32px;}
        li.menuanual5, a.a2015, a.a2014, a.a2013, a.a2012, a.a2011, a.a2010, a.a2009{float:left; margin-right:31px;}
        li.menuanual6, a.a2015, a.a2014, a.a2013, a.a2012, a.a2011, a.a2010, a.a2009{float:left; margin-right:5px;}


        a.a2015, a.a2014, a.a2013, a.a2012, a.a2011, a.a2010, a.a2009{width:725px; height:78px;  font-size:0.01em; text-decortation:none;}

        a.a2015{width:76px; background-image: url("imagens/2015-off.png");}
        a.a2015:hover{ background-image: url("imagens/2015-on.png");}




        a.a2014{width:76px; background-image: url("imagens/2014-off.png");}
        a.a2014:hover{background-image: url("imagens/2014-on.png");}


        a.a2013{width:76px; background-image: url("imagens/2013-off.png"); }
        a.a2013:hover{background-image: url("imagens/2013-on.png");}


        a.a2012{width:76px; background-image: url("imagens/2012-off.png"); }
        a.a2012:hover{background-image: url("imagens/2012-on.png");}


        a.a2011{width:76px; background-image: url("imagens/2011-off.png"); }
        a.a2011:hover{background-image: url("imagens/2011-on.png");}


        a.a2010{width:76px; background-image: url("imagens/2011-off.png"); }
        a.a2010:hover{background-image: url("imagens/2011-on.png");}


        a.a2009{width:76px; background-image: url("imagens/2011-off.png"); }
        a.a2009:hover{background-image: url("imagens/2011-on.png");}
```

Comment: Side note: Your css needs work - there's so much redundancy that by adding one or two classes could reduce that by about 20 lines

Comment: Your code only executes when you click on `#Mostradiv2015`? Move the setting of image src outside the click function.